# Create <ul> in custom node.tpl

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I have a node with a lot of images and I want to convert this images in a `<ul>`-list. So I created a `node.tpl`-overwrite page and tried to alter my HTML, but with no result.

```
 <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content['field_themes_body']);
    ?>
    <div class="theme_slider">
        <ul>
        <?php
          dpm($content['field_themes_images']);
          //print theme_item_list($content['field_themes_images']);
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It seems like the dpm of the `$content['field_themes_image']` contains a whole array with all kinds of properties... Is it possible to filter out the images path only?

I've looked at the [theme_item_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7)-function, but with no luck (or I did it wrong).

Comment: do you have individual fields or do you have one field with multiple images?

Comment: One field with multiple images. Multiple fields isn't an option btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you.

```
      hide($content['field_themes_images']);  
      <div class="theme_slider">
        <ul>
        <?php
          foreach ($content['field_themes_images']['#items'] as $key => $img)
          {
            print "<li>";
            print render($content['field_themes_images'][$key]); 
            print "</li>";
          } 
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please don't add 'Hope that helps' and signatures to posts - your name is already visible at the bottom right of the post, and by answering the question I think we can assume you hope to help :)

Comment: will take care of that in future :-)